# Hyperopt and STATUS_FAIL usage with error "ValueError: attempt to get argmin of an empty sequence"

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, hyperopt

I'm experimenting with Hyperopt and scikit-learn. As far as I know, you only have to provide a dictionary `{'status':STATUS_FAIL}` for the case when there is no a convergence, but I'm facing an error message. I'm not quite sure if I'm missing some data, parameter or key in the returned dictionary of whether I'm misundertanding something on Hyperopt usage.

Thinking it could be any additional and necesary element in the dictionary, I already tried some combinations, like for example:

```
{'status': STATUS_FAIL, 'loss': 1, 'params': params, 'test': [0, 0], 'train': [0, 0]}
```

My code looks like:

```
def objective(params=None):
            '''Objective function for bayesian hyperparameter tuning'''
            if params:
                model.set_params(params)

            try:
                cv_results = cross_validate(model.pipeline, X, y, pids,
                                            scoring='roc_auc', cv=akf,
                                            n_jobs=-1, 
                                            return_train_score=True)
            except ValueError:
                return {'status': STATUS_FAIL }

            # Dictionary with information for evaluation
            return {'loss': 1 - np.mean(cv_results['test_score']),
                    'params': params, 'status': STATUS_OK,
                    'test': cv_results['test_score'],
                    'train': cv_results['train_score']}
```

which is my objective function that I'm using at:

```
    fmin(fn=objective, space=param_grid, algo=tpe.suggest,
         max_evals=iter, trials=bayes_trials,
         show_progressbar=not quiet)
```

and the error message received is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/evasd/miniconda3/envs/ir-models/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 56, in _wrapfunc
    return getattr(obj, method)(*args, **kwds)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'argmin'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File "/home/evasd/miniconda3/envs/ir-models/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperopt/fmin.py", line 409, in fmin
    return trials.argmin
  File "/home/evasd/miniconda3/envs/ir-models/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperopt/base.py", line 590, in argmin
    best_trial = self.best_trial
  File "/home/evasd/miniconda3/envs/ir-models/lib/python3.6/site-packages/hyperopt/base.py", line 585, in best_trial
    best = np.argmin(losses)
  File "/home/evasd/miniconda3/envs/ir-models/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 1172, in argmin
    return _wrapfunc(a, 'argmin', axis=axis, out=out)
  File "/home/evasd/miniconda3/envs/ir-models/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 66, in _wrapfunc
    return _wrapit(obj, method, *args, **kwds)
  File "/home/evasd/miniconda3/envs/ir-models/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/fromnumeric.py", line 46, in _wrapit
    result = getattr(asarray(obj), method)(*args, **kwds)
ValueError: attempt to get argmin of an empty sequence
```